# Is there any difference between new object() and new Object() in c# language?

Tags: c#

While studying the Unity Singleton pattern, I saw code like this on the web. I've seen syntax starting with lowercase `o`. If you're implementing an object, don't you have to use capital `O`? Below is the phrase I saw.

```cs
private static object syncobj = new object();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the framework, the class is `Object`. But C# has an alias defined - `object` - which the compiler translates as Object during compilation.

C# does the same for a few other 'basic' types: int for Int32, long for Int64, and  a few others I don't remember.